# How to retrieve all Tag documents referred in the given post?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, tags

I have following Post and Tag models. Posts have tags array field containing tagIds.

```
      var telescopeId1 = Posts.insert({
             title: 'What is/are the main type',
             userId: sacha._id,
             author: sacha.profile.name,
             details: 'Can someone recommend...',
             submitted: new Date(now - 9 * 3600 * 1000),
             commentsCount: 1,
             tags: [{tagId: valveTagId},{tagId: pumpTagId}]
         });

    var valveTagId = Tags.insert({
        slug: 'valve-tags',
        name: 'valve tags',
        submitted: new Date(now - 7 * 3600 * 1000),
        description: 'Valve tags help relay.'
     });

    var pumpTagId = Tags.insert({
        slug: 'pump',
        name: 'pump',
        submitted: new Date(now - 7 * 3600 * 1000),
        description: 'PUMP is..,'
     });
```

In Meteor i am trying to retrieve all Tag documents referred in the given post using following function:

```
tags: function() {        
    return Tags.find({_id: this.tags.tagId});
}
```

But i get empty tags array object in return, why?

Comment: is this `this.tags.tagId` an array or one single value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to make a few assumptions:

1. The code above executes in an order which gives defined values for `valveTagId` and `pumpTagId`.
2. The context (`this`) in your `tags` helper is a post document.

**problem**

The helper is attempting to do the following:

```js
Tags.find({_id: [{tagId: valveTagId}, {tagId: pumpTagId}].tagId});
```

This doesn't really make any sense, as the array doesn't have a `tagId` property.

**solution**

A correct implementation would extract all of the ids and `find` tags with an `_id` in that list. This should work:

```js
tags: function() {
  var tagIds = _.pluck(this.tags, 'tagId');
  return Tags.find({_id: {$in: tagIds}});
}
```

**improved solution**

The tag ids are stored in an awkward way for performing this join. Instead of storing:

```
tags: [{tagId: valveTagId}, {tagId: pumpTagId}]
```

consider storing an array of ids like this:

```
tags: [valveTagId, pumpTagId]
```

Now the helper can be written as:

```js
tags: function() {
  return Tags.find({_id: {$in: this.tags}});
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer. Both the solutions working exactly as it suppose to. I had tried the second solution but i guess did not reset the database to change the model.

Answer (score 2):

`this.tags` would be an array. So it doesn't have a `tagId` property.

This is how you would find all tags:

```
var tagIds = _.pluck(this.tags, 'tagId');
return Tags.find({_id: {$in: tagIds}});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer.